# Proper use of semantic HTML on a webpage: is the article element appropriate?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Is the `article` (or `section`) element appropriate on a homepage?

I am not sure since the content of homepage is mostly a bunch of summaries referring to the content that should be included in an `article` element (on a separate page).

Comment: It depends on the content. Not all homepages are the same. What do you mean with "summaries"? Ideally you would show or describe such a summary in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rule of thumb I follow is to only use `<article>` or `<section>` if there is a corresponding `<h#>`.

So this is more appropriate:

```
<h1>Home Page</h1>

<p>
Hi.
</p>

<article>
 <h2>Sub-Head</h2>
 <p>
 Hello.
 </p>
</article>
```

Than this:

```
<h1>Home Page</h1>

<p>
Hi.
</p>

<article>
 <p>
 Hello.
 </p>
</article>
```

Do not add a heading just to make it work. The value of a heading should be determined by the nature of the content, not a desire to shoehorn the elements you want.

With an example URL or image of your intended layout and content, I could offer more context.

Also, consider that if you have one contiguous piece of content (like how a sub-page generally is about one thing), you would not wrap the entire page in `<article>` but you would wrap it in `<main>` instead.

For a bit more, check out this [piece on `<section>`](https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2013/10/using-html5-section-element/) from W3C HTML5, WCAG, and ARIA spec participant and accessibility advocate Léonie Watson.